# Black screen appears for a long time after splash screen in Android Worklight application

Tags: android, dojo, load, ibm-mobilefirst, splash-screen

We have developed a Worklight application using Worklight 6.1 and we have kept minimum dojo files required in it.

In Android devices, It is showing a black screen for a long time after the splash screen is shown.

Comment: does the app ever get past the black screen?  Are there any errors in LogCat?

Comment: Is it only on the very first installation of the app, or any subsequent launches as well?

Comment: yes, After 2min I'm getting app screen. Interestingly, this black screen disappears in 1 or 2 seconds in nexus devices.
I can see 
     Started copying files to local storage... in logcat console

Comment: @IdanAdar, Yes, It is happening only for the first launch of app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please wait for Worklight 6.1.0.1 to be released in early March (soon), which will include improvements in the area of application launch time, specifically this should enhance significantly the application first startup time.

Comment: Don't we have any other option. Because user are being confused that the app got crashed or some error occurred.

Comment: You can open a PMR  to receive an iFix, but by the time that will happen the release will likely take place...

Comment: Can you please tell me how to open a PMR? and Cleint is also saying he did not face this issue with other worklight apps. How is it possible?

Comment: If you are an IBM customer you should probably have an IBM contact person, they - or you - can open a support call...

Comment: Cleint is also saying he did not face this issue with other worklight apps. How is it possible?

Comment: I don't know Vinay. Every app is its own. If you client requires support they need to open a PMR. That's the official support path.

Comment: @Vinay: When you contact IBM support, please refer to this stackoverflow question. You can request a "testfix for 29753", which contains the performance improvement you are looking for. The support team can explain to you the details about the testfix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Idan Adar for letting me know. The Worklight fix(6.1.0.01) is rolled out and the blackscreen issue in android apps is resolved now with the new fixpack.

Comment: So why write this as a new answer instead of marking the existing one?